# How to redefine library functionality in project?

Tags: android, android-library

I have library project that implements most of application functionality, it's like a template of application. Every project that uses this library can redefine some resources, themes and so on. Main case is colors and urls to get information, that this applicatoin would show. But to redefine some code is more problematic. For example there is view that displays information from xml, but xml is different and I need to parse it differently. My current realization is like this.

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {

    public setData(XmlData xml) {
         //call to helpers static method to get parsed data from xml
         ArrayList<Item> items = ParseHelper.getItems(xml);
    }

}
```

So what I need is only change some logic inside ParseHelper. Now I see only one way, to redefine layout.xml to change MyView to ProjectMyView in which I'll change method setData to use another ParseHelper. But it's not good.

Maybe there is some patterns or another ways to solve this?

I think another way to use different classes from library or project is to use reflaction. For example packages in project is differs only by name (com.library.helpers and com.project.helpers) and check for class in project, if exists use it, if no use from library. But I think it will use many resources.

Can anyone share their experience?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `MyView` as abstract, and let `setData` as an unimplemented method and forcing all subclasses to implement this method like this:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractView extends LinearLayout {
    public abstract setData(XmlData xml);
}
```

Them, you library has an class that extends `MyAbstractView` with the most usual implementation like this:

```
public class MyView extends MyAbstractView {
    public setData(XmlData xml) {
        //call to helpers static method to get parsed data from xml
        ArrayList<Item> items = ParseHelper.getItems(xml);
    }
}
```

For those which want a different implementation, they just need to also extend `MyAbstractView`.

Finally, the caller or these objects just need to do something like this:

```
public void init(MyAbstractView arg, XmlData xml) {
    arg.setData(xml);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, but again I need to override layout.xml to replace MyView with new one with new implementation of setData method.

Comment: Ok, I missed that from your question. In this case, I can just think in an un-elegant way: in your activity, before call `setContentView(R.layout.main_layout)`, you can look for an default resource for the overlay layout and use it if found. The API to querry for a resource by its name is `Resources.getIdentifier()`. So, you could do `Resources res = getResources(); int overlay = res.getIndentifier("overlay_layout", "layout", "my.app.packagename"); if (overlay == 0) overlay = R.id.main_layout; setContentView(overlay);`

Comment: Too many changes. I can easily make layout file with same name in project and it will be taken from project not from library.